# How do i create a namespace and constructor in c++ in a dll project?

Tags: c#, c++, c

I created on my visual studio 2012 pro a new dll project and the main .cpp file is empty except this line:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

In this dll project I have a new c language item(module) I added with some functions inside.

In fact I want to create in my main .cpp file some functions that will call the function from the c item(module).

For example in the .cpp file I will have something like this:

```
void start()

{

   encoder.start();

}
```

Then in the .cpp I need to add a constructor so I can call there the start()

How should I do it ?

Here is an example in my solution i have two projects one console application one dll.
This is the content of the main cpp file from the console application project:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"

extern "C" {
    void  video_encode_example(const char *filename);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    video_encode_example("adi.avi");
    return 0;
}
```

vide_encode_example is a function from this c item(file/module) i created in the console application project. I have a file called example.c and the video_encode_example is in the example.c

Now i added to the solution a new dll project and the main.cpp file is empty except the line: #include "stdafx.h"

What i want to do in this dll project in the main.cpp is two things:

1. To create some function for example

   void thisstart()
      {
      }

Then i want to in this start function to call a start() function which is in a c file/module i created in the dll project.

So it should look like:

```
void thisstart()
  {
    start();
  }
```

Where start(); is from the c module/file

Then i'm going to use this dll in c# and in c# i want to be able to use the thisstart() function.

**EDIT**

This is the main.h content:

```
namespace dllproj{

    extern "C" void start();
    void thisstart();
}
```

I'm getting and two errors now on dllproj:

1. Error    2   error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'namespace'
2. 4   IntelliSense: expected an identifier

Then this is the cpp file content now:

```
#define dllproj;

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"
#include "main.h"

void thisstart()
 {
     dllproj;::start();
 }
```

And i'm getting two errors:

1. on the define line: Error    1   error C2008: ';' : unexpected in macro definition
2. on the dllproj;::start(); Error  3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'

Please show me the complete solution and explain to me also which variable later in CSHARP i will use with the dll to make an instance for it and to call this function/s in the cpp ?

In csharp for example when i add the dll : test = new something(); then test.thisstart();

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. I think it would help if you posted the code you have written. Doesn't matter if it is wrong, it will help people understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: should it not be `start()` embedded inside `encode.start()`? you example is trying to call c++ from c i guess? please clarify

Comment: Why do you think you need a constructor and/or namespace? Have you used either in the past? Why do you think their usage in a DLL is different from that in any other type of project? Are you sure you want a DLL?

Comment: n.m i have two projects in one solution. The first project also in c++ but console application in the main.cpp file it created automatic main which is like a constructor. Then i added a new project to the solution this time a dll type and the main.cpp file is empty. I will update my question to clarify it.

Comment: Updated my question. I need in the dll project to create a function/s that will call inside another functions i have in a c langauge file/module i created in this dll project. And then i need to use this dll from c# and to be able to call the function/s from the main.cpp file. So if i'm in c# i will be able to type something.thisstart(); or something.config(); in c# i will make an instance for the dll and i will be able then to use the functions in the main.cpp file.

Comment: one clarification is `start()` in console app or dll? and if true you want to call this `start()` from dll's `thisstart()` right?

Comment: right start() is in the dll project in a (c language file i create test.c) so in thisstart() i want to call start() and in c# i want to call thisstart() for example in c# it will be like: something.thisstart(); so thisstart() in csharp will call the start() in the c++

Comment: @BenKochavi  error 1 is because you have added `;` in the define line, remove that. and error 2 is just extra semicolon after `dllproj;::start()`. make it like so `dllproj::start()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments **"start() is in the dll project in a (c language file i create test.c)"**

1) create a header file e.g main.h and add the following

```
namespace dllproj{

    extern "c" 
    {
       extern void start();
    }
    void thisstart();
}
```

2)add main.h to main.cpp and define `thisstart()`

```
 void dllproj::thisstart()
 {
     dllproj::start();
 }
```

make sure start() is declared with `__declspec(dllexport)` in the dll.

Comment: How do i add the h file i created to the cpp file ?

Comment: @BenKochavi error 1 is because you have added ; in the define line, remove that. and error 2 is just extra semicolon after dllproj;::start(). make it like so dllproj::start().

Comment: The C# thing i cant help you because I DONT KNOW C#. sorry

Comment: I'm still getting an error in the h file: Error 1 error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'namespace' i copied it now as your code ot the h file and getting this error.

Comment: And in the cpp file i'm getting an error on the dllproj::start(); after all changes say: Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'

Comment: I didn't use this: __declspec(dllexport) should i use it ? Where excatly in the cpp or h ?

Comment: i checked now with your test cases and according to how i showed you and it worked for me? you have syntax error which can be solved if we can see the code. the `_declspec` should be added for every function in the dll. you need a lot to read up if you dont know all this. [DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx). please do look into it and you'l get a better idea.